# Selenium IDE - click appears to work but not getting recorded in the database

Tags: selenium, webforms, automation, selenium-ide

I'm using Selenium IDE on this website: http://sg.sensemaker-suite.com/collector/modifyfragment.gsp
to do data-driven entry using an XML file.

My test suite runs a loop using data from the XML file where it:
1. Enters the user name, project, language, and the ID. Clicks "load fragment"... loads and page numbers pop up.
2. Click "16" and waits to load. 
3. Enters text in a field and then final click to "save modified fragment". 
4. Captures a successfully entered alert.

I've created the test suite and it appears to be working when I watch it run on FireFox. Everything gets entered properly and clicked and it loops properly to the end. However, when I go back into the database, the data I entered isn't there. Could it be my last click and alert capture are incorrect?

```
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>name=ModifyFragment</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=ModifyFragment</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertAlert</td>
    <td>Your entry saved successfully</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

I've tried different last methods ClickAt, MouseOver, MouseDown, MouseUp. Nothing works.

When I enter everything manually, it works. However when I use Selenium to do everything but the final click and then click it manually myself, it doesn't register in the database. Any ideas on what else I can try?